# Python web2py print to screen

Tags: python, web2py

I'm new to programming (still a student). I was teaching myself Python, tried running a program on a webserver, and decided to use web2py as it is geared for beginners like me.  The program runs fine from the command prompt, but doesn't execute the print statements properly on the webpage it makes.  I've been going over web2py documentation and the tutorials trying to find how to just basically print something without returning it and closing the function.  When I run this:

```
def main():
            url = "http://<someurl>"
            if url[len(url) - 1] == '/':
                url = url[:len(url) - 1]
            maxdepth = 3
            maxpages = 10
            index_cnt = 4
            index = crawl_web(url,maxpages,maxdepth)
            print "Printing index..."
            for i,e in enumerate(index):
                if i >= index_cnt:
                    return
                print "'{}' appears in the following urls:".format(e[0])
                for i,u in enumerate(e[1]):
                    print "    {}".format(u)
                    return "    {}".format(u)  ##only this line printed in web2py page
```

Only the 'return' at the end actually shows on the page.  I know that there's some different syntax when using web2py, but the example code I found all seems to show a return, response.flash, response.print, using print str(DIV()) and a few others I found but am getting nowhere with.  Also when I 'return index' that returns 'None' -- I'd think it would return the values that are then later supposed to be printed by the for loop.

The 'index()' function gets a list of url's, but the supporting functions are fairly long but have not returned any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to appear in the browser, do not use print (that is for outputting to a Python shell). If you want the browser to display something, your function has to `return` it (you can also raise an [`HTTP` exception](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#HTTP-and-redirect), which is ultimately what the framework does when your function returns a response).

If you haven't already done so, I highly recommend reading through the first few chapters of [the book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29) to get a better understanding of how the framework (and web frameworks in general) work. In particular, look [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Workflow) and [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/01#Model-View-Controller).

Comment: I believe web2py allows to actually return response piece-by-piece (aka. stream). This may be something that OP could use to actually do what he said (return something to the browser, but not finish the execution). However it is more complex than just returning some string from function.

Comment: You can stream a response, but that doesn't appear to be applicable in this case. A standard function and associated view should work. The confusion appears to be over usage of the `print` statement. To display the value of `some_variable` on the returned web page, you do `{{=some_variable}}` in the view rather than `print some_variable` in the controller.

Comment: Yup, it looks like it. My proposal was about meeting both requirements OP mentioned: "_(...) print something without returning it and closing the function_". That is surely not the best solution (OP needs something a lot simpler, like just outputting variable in the template), but rather another approach to answering the question. Anyway, upvote goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use print directly in your controller. You can return as `dict` or `str` to views where you have to use template syntax to print.